# SQL server query to get this output

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query which i am unable to get the output.
Below is the query to be executed

Q: 2.   Write a query to find the city Name, Id and Count that has got maximum number of vehicles associated.

Now, Given is the one table on which the query should be executed.

```
Vehicle_Detail_ID   City_ID
56                    242
57                    242
58                    242
59                    243
60                    241
61                    242
62                    245
```

Another table which has the city name

```
City_ID City_Name
242          Bangalore
243          ChamarajNager
241          Bellary
245          Chitradurga
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
City_ID No_Vehicles
242          4
```

Please tell me how to write the query which fetches me the right output.

Given below is the query which gives the city Id and its vehicle count.
TRIED:

```
SELECT c.city_id, COUNT(c.City_ID) AS NO_vehicles
  FROM city c, vehicle_details v 
 WHERE c.City_ID = v.City_ID
 GROUP BY c.City_ID
```

ACTUAL OUTPUT

```
City_ID No_Vehicles
242             4
243             1
241             1
245             1
```

Please help me to get max of these as shown in EXPECTED OUTPUT.

Comment: What database? Is this homework by any chance?

Comment: Which RDBMS? You'd be looking at either `SELECT TOP 1 ... ORDER BY COUNT(...) DESC` or `LIMIT 1` or variations thereof.

Comment: You're halfway there.  Now add a condition to limit the results to the top result.

Comment: You haven't answered which database do you use. Sql Server, MySql, Oracle, Informix, db2, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE V_ddetails(Vehicle_Detail_ID int,City_ID int)
INSERT INTO V_ddetails 
VALUES(56,242),(57,242),(58,242),(59,243),(60, 241),(61,242),(62,245)

CREATE TABLE city(City_ID int, City_Name varchar(50))

INSERT INTO city
VALUES(242,'Bangalore'),(243,'ChamarajNager'),(241,'Bellary'),(245,'Chitradurga')

select top 1 v.City_ID,COUNT(*) as No_Vehicles from V_ddetails v inner join city c
on v.City_ID =c.City_ID 
group by v.City_ID 
order by No_Vehicles desc
```

Comment: @missReclusive be aware that this does not cover the siuation of 2 cities being tied with 4 vehicles each. Compiler will display which ever comes first under no particular logic

Answer (score 1):

// Solution 1

```
Select top 1 v.cityID,count(*) as c 
from tblVehicle as v 
group by cityID
order by c desc
```

// Solution 2 with cityName

```
Select top 1 a.cityID,a.cityName,Count(*) as c 
from tblCity as a
inner join tblVehicle as b
    on a.cityID=b.cityID
group by a.cityID,a.cityName
order by c desc
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select TOP 1 c.city_id,COUNT(c.City_ID) as NO_vehicles 
from city c,vehicle_details v 
where c.City_ID=v.City_ID 
group by c.City_ID.
```

Comment: You can [indent your code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I think with the partition functions yand a CTE you can do this [ON FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef8e6/2)

```
CREATE TABLE V_details(Vehicle_Detail_ID int,City_ID int) 
INSERT INTO V_details  
VALUES
(56,242),
(57,242),
(58,242),
(59,243),
(60, 241),
(60, 241),
(60, 241),
(60, 241),
(61,242),
(62,245)  

CREATE TABLE city(City_ID int, City_Name varchar(50))  
INSERT INTO city 
VALUES
(242,'Bangalore'),
(243,'ChamarajNager'),
(241,'Bellary'),
(245,'Chitradurga') 




   ;with initdata_cte as  
(     
  SELECT              
  c.city_id             
  , COUNT(c.City_ID) AS NO_vehicles                
  , RANK() over (order by c.city_id) rnk     
  FROM city c, V_details v        
  WHERE c.City_ID = v.City_ID       
  GROUP BY c.City_ID  
) 
, rnk_cte as 
(     
  SELECT              
  city_id             
  , NO_vehicles                
  , RANK() over (order by NO_vehicles desc) rnk     
  FROM initdata_cte     
) 
select * from rnk_cte where rnk =1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE V_ddetails(Vehicle_Detail_ID int,City_ID int)
INSERT INTO V_ddetails 
VALUES(56,242),(57,242),(58,242),(59,243),(60, 241),(61,242),(62,245)

select City_ID,COUNT(*) as No_Vehicles  from V_ddetails 
where city_id=242
group by City_ID
```

Comment: The idea was to find city_id having highest count of vehicles. If you know the answer to that question, you do not need to write a query in the first place.

Comment: Ok Try the latest query posted here.

Comment: you can't do that Anand - that's sort of cheating !

Comment: @whytheq -- what is the problem,what did I do?

Comment: @AnandPhadke you've put this in the answer `where city_id=242` ... how can the questioner use that in a general script ?

Comment: Please see my latest answer.Initially I was confused so added new answer.

Comment: your latest answer is good; although what if two cities are both the maximum? this -1 just means that people in the future will not use this answer - it's no big deal Anand (I got -5 for one of my questions yesterday...just a case of moving on)

Comment: In that case we can use the same sql query with little modification to get the desired answer.But I did not understand what worong I did ere so that you downgraded my answer.